# xslt subgroups of groups without duplicates

Tags: xml, xslt

after about 3 hours of tinkers with xslt,

I have the following output

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tops>
<topCategory name="cat1">
    <top name="ninja" tuckedIn="0">
        <part path="ninja_abdomen.png" bodyPart="abdomen"/>
        <part path="ninja_humerus_l.png" bodyPart="humerus_l"/>
    </top>
    <top name="ninja" tuckedIn="0">
        <part path="ninja_abdomen.png" bodyPart="abdomen"/>
        <part path="ninja_humerus_l.png" bodyPart="humerus_l"/>
    </top>
    <top name="pirate" tuckedIn="0">
        <part path="pirate_humerus_l.png" bodyPart="humerus_l"/>
    </top>
</topCategory>
<topCategory name="cat2">
    <top name="monk" tuckedIn="1">
        <part path="monk_head.png" bodyPart="head"/>
    </top>
    <top name="monkey" tuckedIn="1">
        <part path="monkey_thorax.png" bodyPart="thorax"/>
        <part path="monkey_neck.png" bodyPart="neck"/>
    </top>
    <top name="monkey" tuckedIn="1">
        <part path="monkey_thorax.png" bodyPart="thorax"/>
        <part path="monkey_neck.png" bodyPart="neck"/>
    </top>
</topCategory>
</tops>
```

The problem is that I have duplicate `<top>`s I would only like to have one entry of `<top>`s for each name. I believe I am very close to the solution, but cant quite figure it out.

the original xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tops>
    <top path = "ninja_abdomen.png" bodyPart = "abdomen" name = "ninja" tuckedIn = "0" topCategory= "cat1"/>
    <top path = "ninja_humerus_l.png" bodyPart = "humerus_l" name = "ninja" tuckedIn = "0" topCategory= "cat1"/>
    <top path = "pirate_humerus_l.png" bodyPart = "humerus_l" name = "pirate" tuckedIn = "0" topCategory= "cat1"/>
    <top path="monk_head.png" bodyPart="head" name="monk" tuckedIn="1" topCategory="cat2"/>
    <top path="monkey_thorax.png" bodyPart="thorax" name="monkey" tuckedIn="1" topCategory="cat2"/>
    <top path="monkey_neck.png" bodyPart="neck" name="monkey" tuckedIn="1" topCategory="cat2"/>
</tops>
```

and xslt file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent = "yes"/>


<xsl:key name="eachTopCategory" match="tops/top" use="@topCategory"/>
<xsl:key name="eachTopName" match="tops/top" use="@name"/>
<xsl:key name="eachTop" match="tops/top" use="concat(@topCategory,'|', @name)"/>
<xsl:key name="eachPart" match="tops/top" use="concat(@bodyPart,'|' ,@name,'|',@topCategory)"/>

<xsl:template match="tops">
    <tops>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="top[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('eachTopCategory',@topCategory)[1])]"/>
    </tops>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="top">
    <topCategory>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="@topCategory" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('eachTopCategory',@topCategory)">
            <xsl:call-template name="sortTops"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </topCategory>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sortTops">
    <top>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="tuckedIn">
            <xsl:value-of select="@tuckedIn" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('eachTop', concat(@topCategory,'|', @name))">
        <xsl:call-template name="sortParts"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </top>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sortParts">
    <part>
        <xsl:attribute name="path">
            <xsl:value-of select="@path" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="bodyPart">
            <xsl:value-of select="@bodyPart" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </part>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

my expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tops>
<topCategory name="cat1">
    <top name="ninja" tuckedIn="0">
        <part path="ninja_abdomen.png" bodyPart="abdomen"/>
        <part path="ninja_humerus_l.png" bodyPart="humerus_l"/>
    </top>
    <top name="pirate" tuckedIn="0">
        <part path="pirate_humerus_l.png" bodyPart="humerus_l"/>
    </top>
</topCategory>
<topCategory name="cat2">
    <top name="monk" tuckedIn="1">
        <part path="monk_head.png" bodyPart="head"/>
    </top>
    <top name="monkey" tuckedIn="1">
        <part path="monkey_thorax.png" bodyPart="thorax"/>
        <part path="monkey_neck.png" bodyPart="neck"/>
    </top>
</topCategory>
</tops>
```

Comment: if anyone is wondering why the original xml file is so flat, its because it is exported from excel, which cannot deal with lists of lists. also, I am transforming with java, with xslt 1.0, so I would really prefer a solution with xslt 1.0

Comment: Could you list your expected output please? Also if you are using Java, then you should have no problem using XSLT 2.0 with Saxon (either Community Edition or commercial). What's the problem with using Saxon?

Comment: Saxon needs to be installed. I'd like my scripts and such to be more portable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you only need to use two **xsl:key** elements here, to do the Muenchian Grouping. One for grouping by 'category' and a second to group by a concatenation of 'category' and 'name'

```
<xsl:key name="eachTopCategory" match="tops/top" use="@topCategory"/>
<xsl:key name="eachTop" match="tops/top" use="concat(@topCategory,'|', @name)"/>
```

You are already correctly applying the templates to group by distinct category name

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="top[generate-id()=generate-id(key('eachTopCategory',@topCategory)[1])]" />
```

But within the template that is matching this, you then need to match the distinct 'name' record, but within the selected category. This is where you use the concatenated key:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="key('eachTopCategory',@topCategory)
      [generate-id()=generate-id(key('eachTop',concat(@topCategory,'|', @name))[1])]" 
      mode="top"/>
```

Note the use of **mode** because you will end up with multiple templates matching **top** elements. Then, within the template that matches these **top** elements for names, you would get the individual parts like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="key('eachTop',concat(@topCategory,'|', @name))" mode="part"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="eachTopCategory" match="tops/top" use="@topCategory"/>
   <xsl:key name="eachTop" match="tops/top" use="concat(@topCategory,'|', @name)"/>

   <xsl:template match="tops">
      <tops>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="top[generate-id()=generate-id(key('eachTopCategory',@topCategory)[1])]" mode="category"/>
      </tops>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="top" mode="category">
      <topCategory name="{@topCategory}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('eachTopCategory',@topCategory)[generate-id()=generate-id(key('eachTop',concat(@topCategory,'|', @name))[1])]" mode="top"/>
      </topCategory>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="top" mode="top">
      <top name="{@name}" tuckedIn="{@tuckedIn}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('eachTop',concat(@topCategory,'|', @name))" mode="part"/>
      </top>
   </xsl:template>   

   <xsl:template match="top" mode="part">
      <part path="{@path}" bodyPart="{@bodyPart}" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is produced

```
<tops>
   <topCategory name="cat1">
      <top name="ninja" tuckedIn="0">
         <part path="ninja_abdomen.png" bodyPart="abdomen"/>
         <part path="ninja_humerus_l.png" bodyPart="humerus_l"/>
      </top>
      <top name="pirate" tuckedIn="0">
         <part path="pirate_humerus_l.png" bodyPart="humerus_l"/>
      </top>
   </topCategory>
   <topCategory name="cat2">
      <top name="monk" tuckedIn="1">
         <part path="monk_head.png" bodyPart="head"/>
      </top>
      <top name="monkey" tuckedIn="1">
         <part path="monkey_thorax.png" bodyPart="thorax"/>
         <part path="monkey_neck.png" bodyPart="neck"/>
      </top>
   </topCategory>
</tops>
```

Note, this could be simplified if you were able to use XSLT2.0 as this has special grouping commands.

Comment: Ah Tim! You beat my post by one minute, and I had an identical solution to you, right down to the mode names!

Comment: Except maybe the treatment of the `@tuckedIn` attribute. As this gets emitted once per `'eachTop'` group, it makes sense to me that this attribute should be including in the grouping expression at that level.

Comment: Yes, your solution would be needed if two 'names' could have different 'tuckedIn' values. I was assuming not in my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to believe that this is what I came up with independently of Tim! It looks like the same solution to me.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:key name="eachTopCategory" match="top" use="@topCategory"/>
<xsl:key name="eachTop" match="top" use="concat(@topCategory,'|', @name,'|',@tuckedIn)"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <tops>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="top[
      generate-id()=generate-id(key('eachTopCategory',@topCategory)[1])]" mode="category"/>
   </tops>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="top" mode="category">
  <topCategory name="{@topCategory}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('eachTopCategory',@topCategory)[
      generate-id()=generate-id(key('eachTop',concat(@topCategory,'|', @name,'|',@tuckedIn))[1])]" mode="top"/>
  </topCategory>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="top" mode="top">
  <top  name="{@name}" tuckedIn="{@tuckedIn}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('eachTop',concat(@topCategory,'|', @name,'|',@tuckedIn))" mode="part" />
  </top>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="top" mode="part">
  <part path="{@path}" bodyPart="{@bodyPart}" />
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```